# ARM assembly MOV and LDR regarding registers

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, arm

I'm writing a compiler for a simple language specification given and using a reference compiler given to me, I've been following the assembly produced and tailoring it to my own compiler.

However in the process of examining the assembly produced by the reference compiler, I am struggling to understand why the assembly I changed causes the second print to not produce anything:

```
.data

msg_0:
    .word 50
    .ascii "NullReferenceError: dereference a null reference\n\0"

msg_1:
    .word 5
    .ascii "%.*s\0"

msg_2:
    .word 3
    .ascii "%d\0"

msg_3:
    .word 1
    .ascii "\0"

.global main
.text

main:
    PUSH {lr}
    SUB sp, sp, #8
    LDR r0, =8
    BL malloc
    MOV r4, r0
    LDR r5, =10
    LDR r0, =4
    BL malloc
    STR r5, [r0]
    STR r0, [r4]
    MOV r5, #'a'
    LDR r0, =1
    BL malloc
    STRB r5, [r0]
    STR r0, [r4, #4]
    STR r4, [sp, #4]
    LDR r4, [sp, #4]
    MOV r0, r4
    BL p_check_null_pointer
    LDR r4, [r4]
    LDR r4, [r4]
    STR r4, [sp, #0]
    LDR r4, [sp, #0]
    MOV r0, r4
    BL p_print_int
    BL p_print_ln
    LDR r4, =42
    LDR r5, [sp, #4]
    MOV r0, r5
    BL p_check_null_pointer
    LDR r5, [r5]
    STR r4, [r5]
    LDR r4, [sp, #4]
    MOV r0, r4
    BL p_check_null_pointer
    LDR r4, [r4]
    LDR r4, [r4]
    STR r4, [sp, #0]
    LDR r4, [sp, #0]
    MOV r0, r4
    BL p_print_int
    BL p_print_ln
    ADD sp, sp, #8
    LDR r0, =0
    POP {pc}
    .ltorg
p_check_null_pointer:
    PUSH {lr}
    CMP r0, #0
    LDREQ r0, =msg_0
    BLEQ p_throw_runtime_error
    POP {pc}
p_throw_runtime_error:
    BL p_print_string
    MOV r0, #-1
    BL exit
p_print_string:
    PUSH {lr}
    LDR r1, [r0]
    ADD r2, r0, #4
    LDR r0, =msg_1
    ADD r0, r0, #4
    BL printf
    MOV r0, #0
    BL fflush
    POP {pc}
p_print_int:
    PUSH {lr}
    MOV r1, r0
    LDR r0, =msg_2
    ADD r0, r0, #4
    BL printf
    MOV r0, #0
    BL fflush
    POP {pc}
p_print_ln:
    PUSH {lr}
    LDR r0, =msg_3
    ADD r0, r0, #4
    BL puts
    MOV r0, #0
    BL fflush
    POP {pc}
```

The assembly here is produced by the following snippet

```
begin
  pair(int, char) p = newpair(10, 'a');
  int f = fst p;
  println f;
  fst p = 42;
  f = fst p;
  println f
end
```

As an extension for my compiler, I have decided to go for compiler optimisation (strength reduction/dead code elimination/peep-hole optimisation etc). So I found the following assembly instructions that I thought I come reduce into one instruction:

```
    LDR r4, [sp, #4]
    MOV r0, r4
```

To

```
        LDR r0, [sp, #4]
```

So in **main** I made changes to the following instructions like above

```
    LDR r4, [sp, #4]
    MOV r0, r4

    LDR r4, [sp, #0]
    MOV r0, r4

    LDR r5, [sp, #4]
    MOV r0, r5

    LDR r4, [sp, #4]
    MOV r0, r4

    LDR r4, [sp, #0]
    MOV r0, r4
```

When I make these modifications, only the first print instruction prints 10. It should also print 42. So I expected

```
10
42
```

But actually after the changes it is

```
10
```

I read the manual and saw that MOV is used for byte values and we should use LDR for anything greater than a byte in size. But why does this not work?

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: That certainly looks valid, does the original code work? The only difference is the value of `r4` afterwards, but that doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: The original code does work, when I make the modification as shown , it does not produce output.

Comment: Oh sorry , I put the wrong example. I edited my answer

Comment: See that's no longer the same, see my first comment. The code `ldr r4, x; mov r0, r4` sets **both** `r4` and `r0` to the same value `x`. If the code later depends on that, your optimization won't work. For example, just after `BL p_check_null_pointer` the code uses `r4` set from before, but if you optimize that away, this `r4` will not hold the required value.

Comment: Edited: But I removed the ldr into r4 making it ldr r0, x, so why is that still incorrect? Ok I see what you mean there, I used r4 again but it didn't have the expected value it needed.

Comment: Have you removed the **subsequent use of `r4`** such as the `LDR r4, [r4]` after the first `BL p_check_null_pointer`? That code expects `r4` to have the value you have optimized out.

Comment: No but I understand what you mean now, because I used r4 straight afterwards, it expected the value of sp+4 which it was never assigned to. Thank you!